# Подскажите web клиент с веб интерфейсом

Tags: веб-программирование, telegram

Подскажите telegram клиент с веб интерфейсом, но в отличии от web.telegram.org нужна возможность хранить сессию телеграма на сервере, для работы нескольких человек в рамках одной сессии из разных браузеров; так же очень желательно что бы клиенты не могли редактировать профиль и выполнять какие-либо действия, кроме общения в чатах.

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, что такого клиента не существует

Comment: Возможно, если Вы опишите задачу (зачем такое надо), можно будет придумать решение